# racoon pure IPSEC VPN, best way to give vpn server an IP address on the VPN?

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04, ipsec, racoon

We are testing a VPN server for DR. We have a rackspace cloud instance, with a pure IPSEC VPN server running in racoon, serving "road warrior" clients. We have some NAT going on on the server to route externally:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.31.31.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source w.x.y.z
```

It works very well, with windows, apple-ios and android clients connecting perfectly.

What we want to do is set the server to host a few web pages on the VPN only, i.e. for the server to have an IP on the VPN. We could do this using [vpnc](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vpnc), to connect to the public IP, but that seems like overkill.

Is there a way we can do this using racoon, or a loopback interface perhaps?

our (test) racoon conf:

```
path pre_shared_key "/etc/racoon/psk.txt";

remote anonymous {
        ph1id 1;
        exchange_mode aggressive,main;
        my_identifier user_fqdn "redacted";
        peers_identifier keyid tag "blah";
        dpd_delay 20;
        ike_frag on;
        nat_traversal on;
        passive on;
        initial_contact off;
        generate_policy unique;
        proposal_check claim;
        lifetime time 24 hour;
        mode_cfg on;
        verify_cert off;

        proposal {
                encryption_algorithm aes;
                hash_algorithm sha1;
                #hash_algorithm md5;
                authentication_method xauth_psk_server;
                dh_group 2;
        }
}

sainfo anonymous {
        remoteid 1;
        lifetime time 12 hour;
        encryption_algorithm aes,3des,blowfish;
        authentication_algorithm hmac_sha1,hmac_md5;
        compression_algorithm deflate;
}

mode_cfg {
        network4 172.31.31.1;
        pool_size 100;
        netmask4 255.255.255.0;
        dns4 8.8.8.8;
        auth_source pam;
        save_passwd on;
}
```

Comment: Did you guys eventually figure out a solution for this?

Comment: No I left this project about a month after asking this. If you find out how then let me know!